# can't apply image gaussian blur filter using slider in matlab

Tags: matlab, user-interface, image-processing, slider, gaussian

I am working in image processing task using matlab,I have made a slider inside a dialog to apply and update gaussian blur filter on an image which is shown in axes
but it can not apply it,it shows that error
Error in ==> MatlabTestProject>name at 392
axes(handles.axes4);

??? Error while evaluating uicontrol Callback

this is my code

```
function mygui()
   out = dialog('WindowStyle', 'normal', 'Name', 'My Dialog','Resize','off');
  hSlider = uicontrol('Style','slider','Min',3,'Max',15,'Value',3,'Callback',@gaussian_blur);
```

%hListener = addlistener(hSlider,'Value','PostSet',@(s,e) disp('hi'));

```
function gaussian_blur(s,e,handles)
global imag;
slider_value = get(s,'Value');
slider_value=round(slider_value);
%display(slider_value);
%disp('hello')
%create filter
%sliderValueTxt=num2str(slider_value);
%set(handles.kSizeValueText ,'String',sliderValueTxt);  
 h = fspecial('gaussian', slider_value,0.5);
imag=imfilter(imag,h,'conv');
   axes(handles.axes4);
  imshow(imag)


 % --------------------------------------------------------------------
 function gaussianBlur_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
 % hObject    handle to gaussianBlur (see GCBO)
 % eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
 % handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

gaussian_dialog_Gui();
```

Answer (score 2):

You're actually really close! All you need to do is include `handles` as an argument to the function `gaussian_blur` when defining the slider's listener object callback.

i.e replace this line: (it looks like a test line though)

```
hListener = addlistener(hSlider,'Value','PostSet',@(s,e) disp('hi'));
```

with something like this:

```
hListener = addlistener(hslider,'Value','PostSet',@(s,e) gaussian_blur(handles));
```

Just to be sure it works I created a test GUI programmatically using an axes and a slider and it works very well! Actually I changed a bit the filter to see an effect on my test image, but it should work as well in your case:

```
function GaussianSlider()
clear
clc
close all

handles.Image = imread('peppers.png');

handles.fig = figure('Position',[500 500 600 600],'Units','pixels');

handles.axes1 = axes('Units','pixels','Position',[50 100 400 400]);
handles.slider = uicontrol('Style','slider','Position',[50 50 400 20],'Min',3,'Max',15,'Value',3);%// I commented this for the purpose of demonstration. 'Callback',@gaussian_blur(handles));

%// That's the important part: add 'handles' as input argument to
%// gaussian_blur.
handles.Listener = addlistener(handles.slider,'Value','PostSet',@(s,e) gaussian_blur(handles));

imshow(handles.Image,'Parent',handles.axes1);
guidata(handles.fig);

    function gaussian_blur(handles)

        slider_value = round(get(handles.slider,'Value'));

        %// I modified a bit the filter to see the effect
        h = fspecial('gaussian',slider_value,slider_value);

        handles.Image=imfilter(handles.Image,h,'conv');
        axes(handles.axes1);
        imshow(handles.Image)

    end

end
```

If we look at 2 screenshots (i.e. 2 different slider positions):

[image]

and after moving the slider:

[image]

That's it! Hope that helps! If something is unclear please tell me.

Oh and in case you do not know: The actual callback of a slider is only executed when you release the button or press either arrow. As long as you hold the slider and move it, it's only the listener's callback that will be executed.

Comment: Did not work with me , I ve got that error                    http://pbrd.co/1yjJjm6

Comment: Oh then it's hard to know what is wrong; it looks like the handles structure of the GUI is not loaded properly. If you copy/paste the above code does it work?

Comment: Mhh that's really  weird. Can you provide a link to your whole code or a small example that I could run on my computer? Like the .m and .fig files?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByUrbAQ4FmuIcVc0Vmtlc1laMEU/view?usp=sharing   this is my project file ,I hope u find a solution

Comment: alright I made it work by adding 'handles' as an argument to the function 'gaussian_dialog_Gui()' that you call in the gaussianBlur_Callback. I.e. using gaussian_dialog_Gui(handles). With my test image the filter does not change anything but the error does not pop up.

Comment: @Barq I see that you asked a question today; did you solve this problem after all or not?

Comment: Ok did you try the code I proposed in my last comment? (Dec 4 at 21h35)? It was working great :)

Comment: Hi,bro peace be with u , I ve found the solution and It is pretty simple,Just declare the name of the slider global and use it in both funtions